# How to open OneDrive documents in Windows 10 partition from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, windows-10

I am trying to access and open documents saved in the OneDrive folder in  Windows 10 partition from ubuntu 18.04, but it tells me that it can not be displayed.

So, how do I open those documents?

Comment: Good question now that there is no longer Ubuntu One web storage. You can log into your OneDrive account on the internet to access your folder from Ubuntu.

Comment: @rufi_gop Can you post a screenshot of error?

Answer (score 0):

### Using OneDrive in Ubuntu

If you have not synced your OneDrive folder to Disk, the data only exists on the cloud.

What worked for me:

- https://onedrive.live.com/about/signin/
- Sign in using the same info as in Windows 10.

The OneDrive folder you see in Windows 10, (Users/username/OneDrive), looks like it contains files and folders but likely just contains links to your data on the Microsoft cloud.